# Why cannot I use CString as return types or parameters in a MFC DLL made for windows CE?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, mfc, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I have got a library which was made for a **desktop** windows project. It is done in **MFC VC++** by somebody else, and it works correctly. I will use one particular function from the library as an example for explaining the situation.

The example function goes like this:

```
CString GetFulPath(); // .h file
```

In the cpp file,

```
CString CwFolderBrowser::GetFullPath()
{
    CString path;
    if(this->M_pIDLIST!=NULL)
    {
        LPTSTR fullPath=path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH);
        ::SHGetPathFromIDList(this->M_pIDLIST, fullPath);   //ITEMIDLISTからパスを得る
        path.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Now, I can include this library in my project and do something like:

```
CwFolderBrowser cFolderBrowser;
if(cFolderBrowser.ShowDialog() == TRUE)
     cPath = cFolderBrowser.GetFullPath();
```

This will show a folder browser dialog and let me choose a folder. It works fine on desktop windows.

Currently, I am working on Windows CE device. We have converted the library for use with Windows CE by removing unsupported functions and stuff. The library compiles and builds correctly without errors.

Next, I create an MFC Smart Device project, include the converted library, its h file and lib files and set the proper directories for dlls. The project builds fine. I can #include the library's h file properly too.

The problem arises as soon as I **call the GetFullPath function**:

```
cPath = cFolderBrowser.GetFullPath();
```

It gives me an unresolved external link error! The Intellisense does show this function in its list and I can choose it and everything. But in vain.

Strangely, If I modify the library and change GetFullPath()'s signature as below,

```
LPCTSTR GetFulPath(); // .h file  LPCTSTR instead of CString
```

In the cpp file,

```
LPCTSTR CwFolderBrowser::GetFullPath()  // Return type changed to LPCTSTR  
{                                       // instead of CString 
     ...                                // Body modified accordingly
}
```

then, the unresolved external Link error disappears and it works!

I am stumped about this strange behaviour, because, I can use CString normally in the MFC Smart Device project and there are no errors. The link error shows up only when I try to call functions from the library (and other such libraries) dll. At the same time, BOOL, int etc. seems to have no problems as function return types.

Ofcourse, I can go through each library and change every instanceof a CString return to LPCTSTR, but that would be a very big change. I would like to know why CString works fine in project as well as dll when on desktop, while, on Win CE, it works in the project but not i the DLL (At the same time, the DLL itself compiles fine without errors wether it uses CString or LPCTSTR!).

So, basically, **I would like to keep the function CString if possible**, and would like to know the reason why this happens. The exact same error also happenes in other libraries too.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I saw a page on ATL & MFC 7.0 which said about using the /Zc:wchat_t option. I have checked the Dll project as well as my application. Both use the same option of 'Treat wchar_t as Built-in type' as Yes. So, that option matches up.
Further, as I mentioned above, changing the function return to LPCTSTR works. The error disappears. Everything is going fine until I convert the returned LPCTSTR back to CString. The CString turns out as empty/Null. This happens both inside the dll code itself, as well as in my application code too.

**UPDATE2:**
Thanks to Michael and Cody, I changed the function to LPCTSTR and made sure that the values were not going out of scope before I could use them like they suggested. Now the empty/Null problem is solved and I can get the path values properly.

The problem that remains is that I have to convert all the CString functions to LPCTSTR, which is not exactly feasible. **I would like to keep the functions as CString**.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic problem and has been asked often here on SO.

This cannot work:

```
LPCTSTR CwFolderBrowser::GetFullPath()
{
    CString path;
    if(this->M_pIDLIST!=NULL)
    {
        LPTSTR fullPath=path.GetBuffer(MAX_PATH);
        ::SHGetPathFromIDList(this->M_pIDLIST, fullPath);  
        path.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
    return (LPCTSTR)path;  // << here you return a pointer to the zero 
                           //    terminated string in the path object,  
}                          //    but path will be deleted as soon as it goes
                           //    out of scope
```

Maybe in some cases the function appears to work because the memory of the deleted CString object has not yet been overwritten.

You should do this (no error treatment here for simplicity):

```
LPCTSTR CwFolderBrowser::GetFullPath(TCHAR *pathbuffer)
{
    if(this->M_pIDLIST!=NULL)
    {
        ::SHGetPathFromIDList(this->M_pIDLIST, pathbuffer);  
    }

    return (LPCTSTR)pathbuffer;
}

...
// call like this
TCHAR pathbuffer[MAX_PATH];
GetFullPath(pathbuffer);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. This one worked.
In the desktop case, the return type was CString, so, I think returning the 'path' variable was fine. But in the CE case, as it is returning a pointer, we have to change things...

Anyways, I tried your suggestion and this part is working correctly. Now the question remains, why can't I use CString as the return type for this function in case of Windows CE?

Comment: As shown in the first example in the question, that was the original function in the Dll for windows desktop version. It compiles fine and works properly. But when I try to compile it for Windows CE, The CString return type causes an Unresolved Linker error which is why I tried to change it from CString to LPCTSTR. if the CString return type worked in Windows CE too, then I can directly use the original function itself as it is without having to change it to LPCTSTR.

Comment: @PRinCEKtd I don't  have an answer for this question, you have actually two different questions.

Comment: Hmmm... Seems so, doesn't it? Should I break up the question into 2 different ones?

Comment: Oohh, I wouldn't do this. This creates a very confusing API. If I saw this, I would have no way to know that you are returning to me a handle to the same buffer that I passed in, or a different one. Generally, when you return a pointer from a function, it implies that the caller takes ownership of that pointer and is responsible for destroying it. But since I already own `pathbuffer`, I might end up double-freeing. I'd have to read the documentation to be sure (if it exists). Just use a single in/out parameter. That is much clearer. Return success as a BOOL or HRESULT.

Comment: Thanks Cody. I understand your point... As I am passing pathbuffer as a parameter and then returning it as return value, I will have no way of knowing what is what because I already own pathbuffer, but am also getting a pointer as return value. Without looking at the code, I would not be able to tell if both of them are same or different.  

 But again, the main question is what could I do to keep it as CString? Any ideas on that one?